# Access wordnet file with nltk without nltk.download()

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to use wordnet without nltk.download('wordnet') as that function is blocked through the companies IT policy. I have downloaded the wordnet file and unzipped it into my local directory and used `nltk.data.path.append("my/wordnet/directory")`. When I try and execute a command say `"jump" in wn.words()` I get the error -

```
Resource wordnet not found. 
Searched in:
- 'my/wordnet/directory'
- 'standard/directories'
```

To be clear, IT is fine with me uploading the file directly.
How do I get nltk to interact with this file?
File found at `https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/`
Corpus number 69.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this solution inside the notes: https://www.nltk.org/data.html .
After creating the appropriate directories and placing the wordnet files inside the corpora directory and pointing nltk.data.path etc to that directory it worked.